# Sessions with tensorflow

Tags: python, session, tensorflow

I'm a tensorflow beginner. So, excuse my question if it is stupied

I checked a github code for implementing CNN using MNIST data and tensorflow.
the link below:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py

However, I need to save the model generated by this code, but don't know how to do it, as this code does not involve the use of sessions, how to incoperate session on it?

Would appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

The linked code is using `tf.estimator.Estimator` to train the model. Its [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) includes how to save the model using `export_savedmodel`. A saved model can be imported by specifying its location through the `model_dir` argument of the `tf.estimator.Estimator` initialiser.

Comment: it saved checkpoints, but not sure how to spcifiy the number of checkpoints (the number of iteration before saving checkpoint). Also, I'm sorry to ask another question. but I want to print the predicted classes on that code. how can I do so without session?